# not valid in this context: PATH+ when source ~/.bash_profile in macos

Tags: macos, terminal

My bash_profile as follows:

```
export PATH+=":/Users/steve/workspace/bash-tools/misc";
```

when I use

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

it said

```
/Users/style/.bash_profile:export:2: not valid in this context: PATH+
```

I searched on Google but found nothing, please help

Comment: Are you using bash, or zsh? That looks like a zsh error message...

Comment: I'm using zsh. Is it a problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

zsh's `export` command doesn't support the `+=` operator, just `=`. The standard way to do this is to explicitly include the old `PATH` value:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/steve/workspace/bash-tools/misc"
```

...but there's another problem. You said this was in your bash_profile, and that's explicitly a *bash* init file, not zsh. If you want setup to be shared between both bash and zsh, I'd recommend doing something like putting the actual setup code in ~/.profile (which is the generic startup file for POSIX login shells), and then `source`ing it from separate ~/.zprofile and ~/.bash_profile files, like this:

```
[ -f ~/.profile ] || source ~/.profile
```

This way, you can also add zsh-only setup in the ~/.zprofile file, bash-only setup in the ~/.bash_profile file, and still have them share most of the setup.

On the other hand, if you only use zsh, then just put it in ~/.zprofile.

Comment: could you give more detail on how to do it, I don't quite get the step to do

Comment: @SteveLam To fix the error you're getting, replace the `export` command in your bash_profile with the one I gave above. To fix your profile setup... that's much more complicated. I'd have to know more about what shells you use and for what, and what's in your current init file(s) to give you much more advice than I did above.